# How to solve module ""QtQuick.Controls" version 2.0 is not installed" on mac

Tags: qml, qt-creator, qtquickcontrols2

I've been getting the error "module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.0 is not installed" on Qt Creator 5.6.13, so i upgraded to 5.11.2 and i'm still getting it.

Here's the part causing it:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: on Windows I have to set `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` correctly, you probably can find the mac-way for that

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i only have the `QML_IMPORT_PATH` which isn't set in the `.pro`, i can't find an answer for what the variable should contain.
I'm a Qt Creator beginner, so thank you for your help.

Comment: Make sure you are using Qt 5.11.2 by adding `message($$QT_VERSION)` in your pro file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you activated your Qt kit in *Projects > Build & Run* as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

use this command to install it on linux

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtquick-controls2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, I was building with the Qt Creator 5.6.3 compiler.

`Projects => Build & Run => change to the corresponding kit`.