# QML on iOS QtQuick.Controls 2.x not installed

Tags: cmake, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I created an application with Qt5.9.3 on iOS 12 and in a qml file, I use a SwipeView so I need:

```
import QtQuick 2.7 // also test 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 // also test 2.1, 2.2
```

But I keep having the error:

```
module "QtQuick.Controls" version 2.0 is not installed
```

In my cmake file, I added the specific modules Quick and QuickControls2, the lib are installed with Qt5.9.3, so I have:

```
set( MY_QT_MODULES Core Gui Qml Quick QuickControls2 all/modules/I/need)
find_package( Qt5 PATHS my/path/to/Qt COMPONENTS $(MY_QT_MODULES) )
```

What is missing in that? Thanks.

Comment: My CMake file says `Qt5::QuickControls2`, maybe prefix is needed? Is for Desktop+Android, not iOS, but since it's CMake that should not make a difference

Comment: Tested but cmake error, doesn't find Qt5::QuickControls2. I don't have error with simply QuickControls2.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I edited.

Comment: I suppose you saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374106/how-to-solve-module-qtquick-controls-version-2-0-is-not-installed-on-mac ?

Comment: I did but I am not under QtCreator. I use .cmake file and Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQuickControls2Plugin)
```

in the main.cpp.